# How do I remove the eyecup from my Nikon D3300?

Tags: nikon-d3300, eyepiece

Could someone please tell me how to remove the rubber eyecup from my Nikon D3300?

Comment: See page 3 of your user manual.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, all you need to do is push the eyecup up or squeeze its sides and pull it up, just like those child-proof cleaning products.

[image]

Comment: you can always mark my answer as 'useful or accepted' or upvote it :)